# Error 2025 that I absolutely don't understand

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to build a point & click game. 
I can drag item from my inventory to the scene. 
I want to make my object disapear when I'm clicking 2 times. 
It's working, but when the object disapear I've got an error 2025.. (I can ignore it and everything is working, but I'd like to correct this error).

My error say :

```
Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca::DraggedItem/removeDraggedItem()
    [C:\Users\Stéphan\Desktop\12 octobre\La Brousse en folie tactile\com\laserdragonuniversity\alpaca\DraggedItem.as:145]
```

Here's when it's happening :

(I click on my inventory, take my item, drag it to the scene, click 2 times anywhere, the item diseapear, I'm clicking on the inventory again --> ERROR 2025)

Here's my removeDraggedItem function :

```
private function removeDraggedItem(e:MouseEvent) {
  if(timer.running==true) {
    if(e.buttonDown) {
      stageRef.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragItem);
      stageRef.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, itemHitTest);
      draggedItem.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, itemClick);
      stageRef.removeChild(draggedItem);
      toolbar.useText.text = "";
      if (stageRef.contains(this))
        stageRef.removeChild(this);
      Mouse.show();
      Engine.playerControl = true;
    }
  } else {
    if(e.buttonDown) {
      timer.start();
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error, I do this:

```
if( itemToBeRemoved.parent )
{
    itemToBeRemoved.parent.removeChild( itemToBeRemoved );
}
```

I can't tell what the problem is in your code as its not showing me the contents of DraggedItem especially like 145. Perhaps you clicking 2 times causes remove-item events that shouldn't?